# Как создать мультиязычный лендинг на Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, вёрстка, мультиязычность

Всем привет! Опыта мало, не судите строго.

Заказ сделать лендинг на трех разных языках и накатить все это добро на wordpress. Так как сайт будет продвигаться на разных площадкак решили создать три идентичных сайта на разных языках.

У меня вопрос: как накатить все три на WP? Для каждой языковой версии будет своя админ панель или все таки одна админка для всех трех?

Answer (score 0):

> У меня вопрос: как накатить все три на WP? Для каждой языковой версии
> будет своя админ панель или все таки одна админка для всех трех?

Непонятно зачем для леддингов ВП, но ничего "на ВП" "накатывать" не нужно. "На ВП" создаётся сайт.

А для мультизычности есть плагины. Polylang например.

Comment: Я хотел натянуть верстку на WP чтобы заказчик мог в дальнейшем добавлять/удалять некоторые постоянно меняющиеся блоки не залезая в код. Или вы хотите сказать что для лендингов это пустая трата времени?

Comment: @YevheniiPolovinchuk некоторые делают лединги и на ВП. Только **я** не понимаю зачем использовать для одностраниченика  огромный комбайн (любую CMS). Для них есть другие инструменты (только не спрашивай какие - я ими не пользуюсь, тк делаю полноценные сайты, а не одностраничники).